# PHP : Function that recognizes data successfully stored in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to find a way in PHP, that once data has successfully been stored in the database, in this case registration data, PHP has a way of recognizing this, maybe with a function, that can then execute the next process, e.g load a page that has a link to users email for account verification.
Also in loading that page is header() the best way to go.
I have a sneaky feeling that sessions might be the way to go. Anyway all advice gratefully received:))))))

The problem I have is that I want to execute the header () at a particular point and I have written this code to do so :

```
         $rowcount = $statement->rowCount();
         if ($rowcount === 1){
         header('Location:verifyemail.php');
          }
```

I've figured that this code as part of the PDO class that I am using can examine whether the row in the MySql database has just been updated through $statement->execute();
However as there is already output the header won't work I get this error :
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at.....
But if I place the header() prior to the output I get this error :
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in.........
I need to get the page to redirect based on the successful database transaction, but already have output by the time I would like to execute that.........
I have seen a JS solution, but if turned off, the site will essentially cease to function properly........

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Answer (score 1):

The database usually returns an error if data could not be stored. When using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) you can do it like this:

```
$db = new PDO(...);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
   $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (?)');
   $stmt->execute(array('something'));
   doSomethingWhenInsertWasSuccessful();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
   doSomethingBecauseInsertWasNotSuccessful();
}
```

You can safely put a `header()`-redirect in the `doSomethingWhenInsertWasSuccessful()` function. Unless your application writes any output beforehand, there is no reason why this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way I know of is to store the data in the database, then re-query the data back out. If the data comes back out, it was obviously stored correctly.

As far as using header or not, I see no problem with it. Just make sure after you set the header, the next line is "exit();" so execution will stop on the current page.